# How to initialize Ubuntu's 17.10 desktop GUI?

Tags: 17.10, vnc

In other words: what should I launch in `~/.vnc/xstartup` config of vnc4server, to get a desktop environment which looks like Ubuntu's.

So far I've got such `~/.vnc/xstartup`:

```
#!/bin/sh

export XKL_XMODMAP_DISABLE=1
unset SESSION_MANAGER
unset DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS

gnome-panel &
gnome-settings-daemon &
nautilus &
gnome-terminal &
```

Which was found on some site, but I clearly don't have gnome-panel or gnome-settings-daemon installed, so I end up with only nautilus being launched... with an ugly pattern on the background, where wallpaper should be.
After I've installed them, I've just confirmed that it's nothing like ubuntu's default environment, and there was still no wallpaper.
What needs to be launched in order to fix this?

Comment: The command that the display manager uses is `gnome-session`, which in turn starts everything else (`gnome-shell`, `nautilus`, etc.).

Comment: Tried it too, results in a black screen.

Comment: What do you have in `/usr/share/xsessions`?

Comment: `gnome.desktop, openbox.desktop, ubuntu-xorg.desktop, gnome-xorg.desktop, ubuntu.desktop, xfce.desktop`